# Why was Harv sick in Diamond Age?

Tags: neal-stephenson, diamond-age

Why was Harv sick in Diamond Age? Wouldn't they have technology to cure those kind of diseases? In other parts of the book, they used nanocytes as defenses to to 'cure broken capillaries in the buttocks'. Besides, he seems to come from hardy stock.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sickness comes from all the nano tech in the air.

> Part the First, Nell sees some­thing pe­cu­liar; Harv ex­plains all:
>
> "See, there's mites around, all the time...They're in the air, in food
>   and water, every­where. And there's rules that these mites are
>   sup­posed to fol­low, and those rules are called pro­to­cols. And
>   there's a pro­to­col from way back that says they're sup­posed to be
>   good for your lungs. They're sup­posed to break down into safe pieces
>   if you breathe one in­side of you." Harv paused at this point,
>   the­atri­cally, to sum­mon forth one more ebon loo­gie, which Nell
>   guessed must be swim­ming with safe mite bits. "But there are peo­ple
>   who break those rules some­times. Who don't fol­low the pro­to­cols.
>   And I guess if there's too many mites in the air all break­ing down
>   in­side your lungs, mil­lions– well maybe those safe pieces aren't so
>   safe if there's mil­lions."

As for why he wasn't cured, there's no specific cite but from the overall tone of the book Harv probably could have been cured if he was wealthy, powerful, connected, or "valuable". Since he's just a common street kid - tough luck.

Comment: If you go back and read carefully, you'll see there are subtle suggestions of asthma and/or emphysema; his coughing becomes gradually worse over time.